# FileLoadException while accessing assembly dlls in project application folder

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, fileloadexception

I want to load assemblies stored inside my project application folder on the `c:` drive.

This is the code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{                    
    Assembly asm = null;
    asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\\SampleProj\\Workspace\\Test_App\\bin\\Debug\\Assemblies");
}
```

The exception I am getting is:

> Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\SampleProj\Workspace\Test_App\bin\Debug\Assemblies' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

I tried the following, but the error remains the same:

1. Keep the project in other drive and access assemblies from there
2. Removed read-only permission from project folder-sub folders
3. Granted full control permissions to Users in project folder properties
4. Clicked on Unblock button for all DLL properties

Please help.

Comment: I'm not clear on your question "are you trying to load an assembly already referred by your project?" The DLLs are in Debug folder of my project under a folder named "Assemblies"

Comment: Never mind that, you are not specifying a correct value. Specify the whole path that includes .dll extension

Comment: You are trying to load a directory, not an assembly.  Kaboom, treating a directory like a file produces a low-level Windows error, ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.  The CLR can't make a better error message out of that.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in the comment, you are not specifying a valid path (you are specifying a folder when you need to specify a dll). If you want to load all the assemblies in that folder use this piece of code:

```
private static List<Assembly> Assemblies = new List<Assembly>();

private static void LoadAllAssemblies(string path)
{
    foreach (var dir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {
        LoadAllAssemblies(Path.Combine(path, dir));
    }

    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
    {
        if (Path.GetExtension(file) == ".dll")
        {
             Assemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(path, file)));   
        }
    }
}
```